# React Native: Android Studio doesn't automatically bundle when building

Tags: react-native

I am building a react native application and we're doing the production release.
I noticed that everything works in my iOS app (there's a build phase that generates the offline bundle) but when I run the release build in Android Studio, my app builds but it crashes because it can't find the bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve my own question:

We changed our build types/flavors to match our desired configuration.

The `react.gradle` file that comes with React Native has a configuration for `Debug` and `Release`, these are the common build tasks in a native application. BUT once you change things up you need to tell the react library in android whether or not you want it to bundle for you.

You can find this in your app's build.gradle (under 
`./android/app/build.gradle`). There's an entire block of guidelines commented out that explain you what to do.

In my case I had to add the following code **before** `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`

```
ext.react = [
    bundleInNameDebug: false,
    bundleInNameBeta: true,
    bundleInNameRelease: true
]
```

> *NameDebug, NameBeta, NameRelease are all custom BuildTypes/BuildFlavors I have configured.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have the signing configuration, it should build a apk for testing when you run `react-native run-android --variant=release` with the offline bundle. If you want to make a release build for Playstore, run `./gradlew assembleRelease` inside the `android` folder.

You can find more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Comment: Hi, running these commands do not make the bundle. My app crashes on startup because it can't find the bundle. It seems I have to manually run `react-native bundle` before building.

My question is if this is normal?

Comment: Looks like something wired going on with your configuration. Thats definitely not normal.

Comment: Thank you, thanks to this I figured it out and answered my own question.