# Is Android Studio supposed to start Metro Bundler when running a React Native app?

Tags: android, react-native

Supposedly the two ways you can start a react native android app are:

1. `react-native run-android` via command line

OR

2. Open your project in android studio and press Run.

The issues I am experiencing are that using option 1, i will get an error that no devices are available:

```
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

and using option 2 results in an emulator starting and the installation of the app successfully, but the JS packager doesnt start as part of this flow.

Now sure, I can easily get around this by either

1. Run the packager manually before starting the app in Studio
2. Starting an emulator before running `react-native run-android`

but it seems like this is indicative of a problem somewhere

I have checked out this similar question here [React Native: Android Studio doesn't automatically bundle when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351748/react-native-android-studio-doesnt-automatically-bundle-when-building) but that is unrelated to whats happening to me

Comment: For testing/building on Android I have always started the emulator and the bundler before running `react-native run-android`

Comment: nah, this is normal

Comment: thank you guys  for confirming that this is expected behavior